# How do I insert <span> tags around the countdown numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdownjs.js

I'm using this countdown code :

```js
var clock = document.getElementById("timeleft"), tdy = new Date(1494979200000);
countdown.setLabels(
  '| <span class="time-label">second</span>| <span class="time-label">minute</span> | <span class="time-label">hour<span> | <span class="time-label">day</span> || <span class="time-label">month</span> ||||',
  '| <span class="time-label">seconds</span> | <span class="time-label">mins</span> | <span class="time-label">hours</span> | <span class="time-label">days</span> || <span class="time-label">months</span> ||||',
  '',
  '',
  'Out of Time','');
clock.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();
setInterval(function(){
  clock.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();
}, 1000);
```

How do I modify the above code to add span tags around the countdown numbers? thanks in advance.

Reference: http://explore.venasolutions.com/Q3-Weekly-Webinar-LP-2.html

Comment: Which plugin are you using for `countdown`?

Comment: Hey Mosh, I'm using this http://countdownjs.org/

Comment: So to clock.innerHTML you want to add <span> tags?

Comment: Something like this <span>5</span> months <span>10</span> days

Comment: that means the output of the countdown function should be between the <span> tags right?

Comment: Yes! that is correct!

Comment: http://countdownjs.org/readme.html "String toHTML(tagName, emptyLabel): formats the Timespan object as an English sentence, with the specified HTML tag wrapped around each unit. If no tag name is provided, "span" is used. e.g., using the same input"..etc, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly what is displayed in the url you have given ,you would have to use the following code using Div tags,

```
var arr=countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        clock.innerHTML= "<div> "+arr+" </div>";
        } 
        setInterval(function(){
            var arr=countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();
            clock.innerHTML= "<div> "+arr+" </div>";
        }, 1000);
```

In case you want the entire text within span tags as you had mentioned you would have to us the following code,

```
var count=countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();
        var arr=count.split(" ");
        clock.innerHTML="";
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            clock.innerHTML+= "<span> "+arr[i]+" </span>";
        } 
        setInterval(function(){
            var count = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();
            var arr=count.split(" ");
            clock.innerHTML="";
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                clock.innerHTML+= "<span> "+arr[i]+" </span>";
            }
          }, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, my jquery chops is very very embarrassing. so using your code. do I insert that code somewhere or am I modifying a line

Comment: this line "clock.innerHTML = countdown(new Date(tdy.getFullYear(), tdy.getMonth(), tdy.getDate(), tdy.getHours(), tdy.getMinutes(), tdy.getSeconds()) ).toString();" has to be replaced by those two lines

Comment: there is one more line of "clock.innerHTML" that can also be replaced by those two lines i mentioned

Comment: I just tried it and it wraps the span tag around everything like so:

<span>5 MONTHS 19 DAYS 9 HOURS 15 MINS 10 SECONDS</span>
 and not <span>5</span> MONTHS <span>19</span> DAYS <span>9</span> HOURS <span>15</span> MINS <span>10</span> SECONDS

Sorry if i didn't explain it right the first time. English is not my first language.

Comment: i have edited it splitting the string using the space and then use it in the innerHTML

Comment: I tried replacing the line with your modified line and it just went crazy. it kept adding new lines of <span> tags after each seconds

Comment: Can you check what you are getting from the arr variable?

Comment: Do you have an url where your code has been deployed?

Comment: give me a second. I'll upload them. Thank you so much for your patience

Comment: no problem ,I have edited it ,can you check whether it is working for you now

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! You're awesome!!! This saved my life! Not exaggerating.

Comment: glad to have helped :)